# Data in future builder is loaded only after restart of app

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, future, provider

I take data from list in provider. When app opened data added there from SharedPreferences, or if it's opened for the first time, first data comes from server and then saved to Shared preferences, from where it anyways added to this List.
The problem is that data appears on the screen only after restart of app, and never in the first start.

```
Future<void> fetchAndSet() async {
    pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    pref.containsKey('users') == true ? getPreferences() : setPreferences();
    return _users;
  }

  setPreferences() async {
    ApiManager()
        .fetch()
        .then((value) => pref.setString('users', value))
        .then((value) => getPreferences());
  }

  Future getPreferences() async {
    var jsonMap = json.decode(pref.getString('users'));
    var isThere = false;
    for (var el in jsonMap) {
      var newEl = User.fromJson(el);
      for (var user in _users) {
        if (user.id == newEl.id) {
          isThere = true;
        }
      }
      if (!isThere) {
        _users.add(newEl);
      }
    }
  }
```

```
     body: FutureBuilder(
        future:
            Provider.of<UsersData>(this.context, listen: true).fetchAndSet(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState !=
                ConnectionState.done
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: Provider.of<UsersData>(this.context, listen: true)
                    .users
                    .length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => DetailsScreen(
                            Provider.of<UsersData>(this.context, listen: true)
                                .users[index]
                                .id))),
                    child: Container(
```

Answer (score 0):

did you test changing `listen` to `false` in this code? i think it's should be `false` not `true`, then change this line:

```dart
Provider.of<UsersData>(this.context, listen: true).fetchAndSet(),
```

to

```dart
Provider.of<UsersData>(this.context, listen: false).fetchAndSet(),
```

Comment: Yes. Doesn't help